# LINQ Group by for keyvaluepair data

Tags: c#, linq, select, group-by, keyvaluepair

Hello I am using Linq in my asp.net mvc application to get the questions as per ids inserted in answer table.

I have table data like this:

[image]

Here in above picture you can see ScheduleId is there in two tables first table which is used to assign question to scheduleid's and second table is for storing the answer of that questions with scheduleid.

Now what I have to do it take questions of scheduled from question table and also get the answer of that question's as Answer like how many star customer has given. like 5 star , 4 star, 3 star etc... etc...

So in second table I have given an example for QuestionId 1 there are 4 answers given with scheduleid 7543.

I want to take the data such a way to get questions list with count of that given answer like questionid 1 will have 4 answers

Q1 5(2 times)
Q1 2(1 time)
Q1 2(3 time)

like this so I have created one class:

```
public class Question
    {
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> AnswerList { get; set; }
    }
```

so as per above class

I have written this query:

```
List<Question> questionList = (from queans in Context.Get<GuestRatingAnswers>()
                                           join regque in Context.Get<GuestRankingQuestions>()
                                            on queans.QuestionId equals regque.Id
                                           orderby queans.QuestionId, queans.AddedOn descending
                                           group new { queans, regque } by new
                                           {
                                               queans.QuestionId,
                                               regque.Question,
                                               regque.AddedOn
                                           }
                               into g
                                           select new Question
                                           {
                                               QuestionId = g.Key.QuestionId,
                                               QuestionText = g.Key.Question
                                               //AnswerList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                                           }).OrderBy(n => n.QuestionId).ToList();

            foreach (var item in questionList)
            {

                var detail = (from queans in Context.Get<GuestRatingAnswers>()
                .GroupBy(n => n.Answer).
                     Select(grp => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(grp.Key.ToString(), grp.Count().ToString()))).ToList();

                var details = (from queans in Context.Get<GuestRatingAnswers>()
                               orderby queans.Answer descending
                               group new { queans } by new
                               {
                                   queans.Answer
                               }
                                into g
                               select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(g.Key.Answer.ToString(), g.Key.Answer.ToString()));
            }
```

In above query in for each I want answer with count of answer as keyvaluepair as well it is incomplete help to complete that or is there any mistake I have done please mention.

query used with var as detail and details are both different just I given for test.

Thanks in advance. :)